# Replicate Gated check-in functionality in Visual Studio + VSO + Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, nunit, githooks, azure-devops

I'm trying to replicate Gated check-in functionality in Visual Studio + VSO + Git.

Actually I'd like to run Unit Tests before code will be committed to local repo OR pushed to remote.

But faced with an issue - there is no Gated check-in functionality in VSO + GIT.

I've tried to configure git hooks - pre-commit hook will work for me - but Visual Studio GIT provider doesn't support Git hooks! Its due to the libgit2 -it is used in Visual Studio and it doesn't support hooks:(

So my question is how can I run NUnit Tests automatically before commit in Visual Studio 2013 + VSO +Git and do not allow bad code get into my repo?

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681746

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gated checkin, or the equivalent has already been added to VSO. If you go to the properties of your Git repo in Admin you should see an additional settings tab when you select a branch.

Check the box to enable build before merge for your MASTER branch and select the build you want to use to validate.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-may-15-vso.aspx

Developers then have to create a pull request to MASTER and pass the gate to get in.

Comment: You can get something close to gated checkins, but this is not feature parity.  It sounds like this doesn't exist yet for VSO.

Comment: How is doing pull requests remotely like running unit tests pre-commit?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is perhaps to use the pull requests feature and merge only the branches where the unit tests pass. You only be able to merge these successfully building.

The other possibility is to use a script like git-build which help you to run a command (build and test) locally before pushing... See [here for explaination](http://blog.javabien.net/2009/12/01/serverless-ci-with-git/) and [here for a more recent script](http://blog.valtech.fr/2013/02/27/comment-git-build-a-remplace-jenkins-egalement-sous-windows/) (sorry for the french...)

Comment: Thanks!

I'll try to implement git-build solution to run tests, as our tests run pretty quickly.
Unfortunately this solution will require that developers use console to push data to repository (git build) instead of using native VS Git provider GUI. 

I've tried to find 'transparent' solution that could allow to use native VS interface, but as I see VS doesn't provide any ability to include custom script in commit/push process.